# firestore query logic works only the first time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore

So my goal here is to have the firestore query logic work every time instead of it working perfectly one time and not working properly every time after that. Currently, I have a function that determines whether a school user can delete an event or not based off the fact if a student has purchased a ticket for this event already.

If even one student has purchased a ticket for this event, the school user cannot delete this event, having this in place will prevent bugs and app crashes. The logic I use is simple, I do a query snapshot to check if there are actually students under the school ID of the school user, and then I do a second query snapshot to see if there are students that have purchased a ticket for the event already.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
   

    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (deleted, view, completion) in
        
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else { return }
        let deleteIndex = client.index(withName: IndexName(rawValue: user.uid))
        let documentid = self.documentsID[indexPath.row].docID
        let algoliaID = self.algoliaObjectID[indexPath.row].algoliaObjectID
        
        
        
        self.getTheSchoolsID { (id) in
            guard let id = id else { return }
            self.db.collection("student_users").whereField("school_id", isEqualTo: id).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard error == nil else { return }
                
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let userUUID = document.documentID
                    self.db.collection("student_users/\(userUUID)/events_bought").whereField("eventID", isEqualTo: documentid).getDocuments { (querySnapshotTwo, error) in
                        guard error == nil else { print(error)
                            return }
                        guard let query = querySnapshotTwo?.isEmpty else { return }
                        if query == false {
                            self.showAlert(title: "Students Have Purchased Tickets For This Event", message: "This event cannot be deleted until all students who have purchased a ticket for this event have completely refunded their purchase. Please be sure to make an announcement that this event will be deleted.")
                            return
                        } else {
                            print(querySnapshotTwo?.count)
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Event", message: "Are you sure you want to delete this event?", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let deleteEvent = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (deletion) in
                                let batch = self.db.batch()
                                let group = DispatchGroup()
                                group.enter()
                                deleteIndex.deleteObject(withID: ObjectID(rawValue: algoliaID)) { (result) in
                                    if case .success(_ ) = result {
                                        group.leave()
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                group.notify(queue: .main) {
                                    let docRef = self.db.document("school_users/\(user.uid)/events/\(documentid)")
                                    batch.deleteDocument(docRef)
                                    batch.commit { (err) in
                                        guard err == nil else { return }
                                    }
                                    self.eventName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                    tableView.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
                            alert.addAction(deleteEvent)
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemRed
    
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
    
}
```

I show two different alerts based off the query result, if the query is empty, the event can be deleted as normal and this is what it would like if you try to delete it.

[image: normal]

Now if a student has already purchased a ticket for this event, the school user should be seeing this alert every time:

[image: purchased]

The issue is that this works perfect the first time, first time as in when I first run the simulator or log out and log back in. Every time after that, it shows the other alert as if no students have purchased a ticket for it, but the purchase is still active which makes me so confused. To keep it brief, the code I am using works, but it doesn't work more than once which I can't figure out for the life of me.

Does anybody know how I can make this firestore query logic work perfect every time?

Comment: That's quite a bit of code for us to parse through so let me ask this; If you have a collection of Events, and each event (a document) has an eventId (being the documentId) and a field that contains a reference to the school and then another field that contains the number of tickets sold, when a user goes to delete that event, wouldn't it be easier to just read the event and see if the tickets sold field is greater than zero?

Comment: Funny thing is I actually tried to implement that, but it would always increment the count wrong, it would increment by like 4 even though one ticket was purchased, I still want to give it another shot in the near future, but I've found a temporary alternative. Thanks for the response regardless. @Jay